# Polymer Neon Animations does not work

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am trying to implement [neon-animation](https://github.com/PolymerElements/neon-animation) on a dialog by using polymer. The animations are not working. The popup is seen, but without any animation effects.

My code is as below:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-dialog-scrollable/paper-dialog-scrollable.html" />
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html" />
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html" />
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html" />
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-item/paper-item-body.html" />
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-icon/iron-icon.html" />
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/neon-animation/animations/scale-up-animation.html"/>
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/neon-animation/animations/fade-out-animation.html"/>
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animation-runner-behavior.html"/>
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animations.html"/>

    <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-styles/paper-styles.html"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section is="my-dialog" onclick="clickHandler(event)">
      <paper-button data-dialog="animated" role="button">raised button</paper-button>
      <paper-dialog id="animated" role="dialog" entry-animation="scale-up-animation" exit-animation="fade-out-animation">
        <h2>Header</h2>
        <paper-dialog-scrollable>
          Loremipsum... gfhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhfgggggggggggggg
        </paper-dialog-scrollable>
        <div class="buttons">
          <paper-button dialog-dismiss>Cancel</paper-button>
          <paper-button dialog-confirm>Accept</paper-button>
        </div>
      </paper-dialog>
    </section>
    <script>
      function clickHandler(e) {
        var button = e.target;
        while (!button.hasAttribute('data-dialog') && button !== document.body) {
          button = button.parentElement;
        }

        if (!button.hasAttribute('data-dialog')) {
          return;
        }

        var id = button.getAttribute('data-dialog');
        var dialog = document.getElementById(id);
        if (dialog) {
          dialog.open();
          }
        }
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please, tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your code and it works. I created a Polymer application with the [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) generator, added the 4 required imports and replaced the *index.html* page by your code.

The 4 required imports are:

- paper-button.html
- paper-dialog.html
- paper-dialog-scrollable.html
- neon-animation.html

The others you have imported are not required. I can only advise to check the imports paths.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Yeoman scaffolding and you are importing from your `index.html` file, then you will need to add a path to your imports that goes up one directory from your `index.html` then over to `bower_components` directory.

The way to do that is to add two dots and a slash to the beginning of the path name. i.e., `../`

**Example:**

The complete import tag should look like this: *(See the two dots?)*

`<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animations.html"/>`

And do that for all your imports.